# position: absolute, padding and responsiveness

Tags: css, responsive-design

What I'm using:

- [Form wizard](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-wizard-and-validation)

It is using `position: absolute on :before`

What I want:

I want to use the navigation:
[image]
 But! I also want to add padding, say 10px, to the parent container so that I get something like this:
[image]

How can I do this and at the same time, keep it responsive?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cjo98n4/)

[Here is the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cjo98n4/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap ".stepwizard" inside a new div

```
<div style="padding:10px;background-color:#fff;">
```